# CSS Change Shape after hover and clicked

Tags: html, css

Recently I was trying to style an input box using CSS. Where when the box hovered, it'll change it width and when it clicked it shape will stay. Meanwhile, if it not clicked and got hovered away it'll back to it's normal width. But the result is not like what I wanted.

Here is the example.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p,
form {
  opacity: 100%;
  font-family: Mosk-Regular;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 130px;
}

input[type=text]:hover {
  width: 180px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-family: Mosk-Bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fName">First Name</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
  <br><br>
  <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I haven't tried the clicked one because I need to learn more JS. But for the hovered away, i don't have any idea how to do it. I have tried the `input[type=text]:hover:after` and `input[type=text]:hover:before` but nothing happend. It makes the input has no animation instead giving it a hovered away animation.

Comment: For transitions, I suggest adding them to the default state of the element. Then just changing the needed data in the event state (ie hover). But that doesn't fix the CLICK issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the transition properties to the default input selector too. It essentially acts as the "unhovered" state. You can also force the wider width while the input has focus with a `:focus` selector.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p,
form {
  opacity: 100%;
  font-family: Mosk-Regular;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 130px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

input[type=text]:hover {
  width: 180px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 180px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-family: Mosk-Bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fName">First Name</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
  <br><br>
  <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This helps me a lot and gives me some knowledge about the ```:focus``` and more about ```transition``` , thanks a lot for the help.